# Unable to access the property of object in event handler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader, eventhandler

i am running my code in the event handler to access the property of object defined using this but not able to access,:

```
  name={
      image:""
     }
      reader.onloadend=function(){
       final=this.result;
      imga.src=final;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(files);
```

Comment: Please read [ask], and include a [mcve].

Comment: [DOM on-event handlers: Event handler's parameters, this binding, and the return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value)